# Randomly select a list then an item from said list, then print it but also print the list it is in

Tags: python

I know how to randomly select something from a list.
I want to randomly select a list and then randomly select a thing from that list, to print it but I also want to be able to print the list the thing is in.

Say there's this:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3]
b = [b1, b2, b3]
```

If it selects b2, I want it to print "b2, b" since b2 is in b. If it selects a1, it should print a.

I'm new to python, so help would be great.

Edit:

```
import random

lists = ['first', 'second'] 
first = ['one', 'word']
second = ['two', 'more', 'and']



selected = random.choice(random.choice(lists))


print(selected)
```

Comment: First, you need a list of lists.

Comment: Okay, I will try to clarify it. I made a list of the lists.

Comment: @lemuria I think that you are close, but not quite there yet.

Comment: `lists` is a list of strings, not a list of lists.

Comment: So, what do I do to solve it?

Comment: A string that's the same as a variable name doesn't become the variable.

Comment: ``lists = [first, second]``

Comment: I'm also running python 2.7.10 just in case. The first answer however gave me a syntax error.

Comment: That is why. Python 2.7 has different syntax than python 3.

Comment: Alright, I've solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```py
import random

possible_lists: [[]] = [
    [1,2], # list a
    [3,4]  # list b
]
selected_list = random.choice(possible_lists)
selected_item = random.choice(selected_list)
print(selected_item, selected_list)
```

Python 2

```py
import random

possible_lists = [
    [1,2], # list a
    [3,4]  # list b
]
selected_list = random.choice(possible_lists)
selected_item = random.choice(selected_list)
print selected_item, selected_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `first` and `second` first. Then use those variables in `lists`, not strings that name the variables.

```
import random

first = ['one', 'word']
second = ['two', 'more', 'and']

lists = [first, second] 

selected_list = random.choice(lists)
selected_string = random.choice(selected_list)

print(selected_list, selected_string)
```

Comment: smart answer, it is much better than mine

Comment: This does not solve the question *Print a random item AND print the list the item is in*

Comment: I've updated the answer to select the list and list item separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
    
lists = ['first', 'second'] 
first = ['one', 'word']
second = ['two', 'more', 'and']
    
    
listused=random.choice(lists)
if listused=="first":
         
    selected = random.choice(first)
else:
    selected=random.choice(second)
    
    
print selected
print listused
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of lists so that you can select from the base list, in which all the lists are, a random list with a random value. You can do, for example, like this:

```
import random

lst = [['first', 'second'],
['one', 'word'],
['two', 'more', 'and']
]

ran_lst = random.choice(lst)

ran_val = random.choice(ran_lst)

print(ran_lst, ran_val)
```